# Generar PDF en memoria no en disco duro

Tags: java, java-8

Como se podría almacenar el pdf en memoria; lo que no quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

```
File newPdf = new File("/var/reports/genera01.pdf")
```

Básicamente no quiero ocupar espacio en el disco ya que después de obtener el PDF lo quiero imprimir con `PrintJob`, el pdf lo voy a generar de un jasper Reports.

Comment: si se puede almacenar en memoria.

Comment: Pasando a la parte seria, esta pregunta, en su estado actual, es demasiado amplia. Te invito a leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ¿Por qué no le dan un tiempo a Heinz a mejorar su pregunta antes de cerrarla?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! ☺ No olvides visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Desafortunadamente tu pregunta incluye muy pocos detalles. Por ejemplo, ¿quieres generar un archivo PDF *al vuelo*, como un reporte? ¿Obtienes el PDF desde una base de datos o es enviado por el usuario? Puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/22697/edit).

Comment: Em realidad no se cierra @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, se pone _en espera_. ¿En espera de qué? Precesiamente de que la mejore. Si no la mejora en 5 días, entonces si que cierra. Cerrar una pregunta no es un castigo (o no debería verse como eso) sino más bien como una __oportunidad de mejora__. ¿Cuál es el mejor momento para cerrar una pregunta con serias deficiencias como esta? Mejor temprano que tarde. La guía es esta [http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Podemos discutir si cerrar o abrir la pregunta en [este chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44973/cerrar-pregunta-22697)

Comment: El pdf ya está en el disco duro, en la ruta, `/var/reports/genera01.pdf` así que el espacio en disco ya está ocupado. Lo que sí se puede hacer es volcarlo en la memoria y borrar el archivo (pobre archivo si se corta la luz).

Answer (score 1):

Un archivo necesariamente tiene que estar en el disco duro. Si lo deseas en memoria, puedes usar un arreglo de bytes que estarán únicamente en memoria (Usar [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) y [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) para leer y escribir arreglos de manera similar a un archivo). El stream de bytes contiene el contenido del archivo.

Ambos(File/ByteArray, Streams) extienden de `java.io.OutputStream` y `java.io.InputStream`, por lo que se pueden usar como supler clases para ocultar la implementación de leer de un archivo o un arreglo de bytes en memoria.

Comment: Más exactamente, un archivo está almacenado en un dispositivo. En Java, es una *representación abstracta* de una **ruta**, desde la cual se leerá o escribirá un flujo de bytes, supeditado a ciertas condiciones del sistema operativo. `java.io.File` no extiende a `java.io.OutputStream`, sino `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`, `java.io.FileOutputStream`, entre otras clases. No obstante, JasperReports también puede escribir a un flujo de bytes implementado como un arreglo de bytes, como ya mencionaste.